# Why does a browser apply CSS styles first before deciding what onclick event handler to call?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I have a single `div` on a page. It has an `onclick` event handler. When the user clicks on that `div` I expect that the event handler will be called. But there is this CSS rule as well: when that `div` has a focus, it will be moved 50 pixels to the right (away from the mouse pointer). As a result of this the `onclick` event handler is not called, even though the user clearly clicked on that `div` at the beginning. It's as if the browser first applies CSS and only after that decides, what did the user clicked on.

I made a simple demo here: https://jsbin.com/yalazam/edit?html,css,console,output Click on the yellow square (that is *the* `div`) in the fourth column and see the console in the third column. Only a message `"focus square"` will appear, but not a `"click square"`.

Does this behavior makes any sense? Is there any case when it is useful? Or should I just accept it as a weird behavior of the browser?

Comment: what's "weird" about it? The `click` event never fires because that only registers when you have a `mousedown` followed by a `mouseup` *on the same element*, which your "jumping" behaviour necessarily avoids. If you REALLY need this effect then use `mouseDown` rather than click, but the real answer is not to do this, as it will annoy your users no end.

Comment: Click the html snippet icon in stackoverflow (looks like `<>`) and you can directly embed html,css, and javascript  examples

Comment: I agree with @Robin-Zigmond, the behaviour is entirely as expected. If you mousedown on the div (the console shows focus square) but hold the mouse, move it to the moved div and then release the mouse button, the console shows click square as you have now completed the click. As explained, a click involved both mousedown and mouseup.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Thank you, now it makes sense. If you write your comment as a proper answer I will accept it.

Comment: thanks @Ytus, happy to help - I'll do that when I have time tonight

Comment: Now done, including going into a bit more detail with a link to the MDN docs (checking which also allowed me to be a bit more accurate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant point here consists in the [definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event) of what a click event is:

> An element receives a `click` event when a pointing device button (such as a mouse's primary mouse button) is both pressed and released while the pointer is located inside the element.
> If the button is pressed on one element and the pointer is moved outside the element before the button is released, the event is fired on the most specific ancestor element that contained both elements.

This means that in your example, no `click` event is fired on the div you're targeting, because although the mouse press happens inside that div, the release happens after it has moved (unless the user does something unnatural) so is not within the same element. A `click` event *will* fire on the `body` (which in your example is the "most specific ancestor" referred to on MDN), but that won't be terribly helpful to you to listen for - because a `click` on the `body` can happen in many other ways, and you can't event use the event's `target` property to see where it originated, because in this case that is the `body` itself as explained.

If you *really* need this effect then use the `mouseDown` or `mouseUp` event rather than `click`, depending on what feels most natural to you. But the real answer is not to do this, as it is likely to be unexpected to your users and annoy them.